# "Reload" .txt File in Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: file, jupyter-notebook, reload

I'm assisting a basic data-analysis course and upon showing students how to read .txt Files into their Jupyter Notebooks using numpy.loadtxt, one of them ran into issues. She had created a .txt file and typed in some random numbers. All the file contents were properly displayed by her notebook, however, when she made changes to the file, the notebook wouldn't recognise those changes. Instead, it kept displaying the same numbers from when she first loaded the file into the notebook.

I made sure she had saved her changes properly and couldn't find any other potential error sources. In hindsight, maybe restarting the kernel would have done the trick, but I'm no expert on these notebooks and the issue never occurs for me, so I can't test it out.

Are there other ways of "reloading" any file that has at some point been loaded into the Notebook, to make the notebook account for changes to the file? I know importlib.reload does this for modules, but so far, I can't seem to find any equivalent function that does this for any file (.txt, .csv etc.).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. When I save the text file, and re-run the cell that loads data from it using numpy, it has the new values in the corresponding array produced. Don't even need to restart the kernel. If you ever are able to reproduce it, I'd suggest providing example code that exhibits this. And a screenshot accompanying this. Normally screenshots aren't encouraged but since this is a behavior, it is advised in addition to actual code.

Comment: Since it shouldn't be happening, I think your question, "Are there other ways of "reloading" any file that has at some point been loaded into the Notebook, to make the notebook account for changes to the file?" is moot, but of course there's other ways to bring the data. You can just show it with `cat` or read it in with `pandas` or `csv`. But that isn't really the issue here.